# Programmatically Highlight ListView Item

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

There are countless answers for this same problem, however none of them seem to work for me and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my `activity.xml`:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_view_selector" />
```

Here is `list_view_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_item_border_selected" />
</selector>
```

Here is `list_view_item_border_selected.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

And finally, in my activity (and running on the UI thread):

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.trackList);
listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

I've also tried other `android:state_X` as well as various method calls such as `.setSelection(0)`.

None of these seem to do anything. I can get an item to highlight when touched by changing the `list_view_selector.xml` to have only a default state, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_view_item_border_selected" />
</selector>
```

However this doesn't help me when I want to change selection from code. What am I doing wrong?